# Flash AS3 is it possible to change a value inside a symbol?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textbox, symbols

Hello and thanks for your time :)

Right now I have a symbol where i have a textbox inside and i want to change the value of the textbox inside it but i cant using the normal code i normal would do

```
Textbox_score.text = score;
```

that dosent work then its inside the symbol :( so do any one have any clue how to do this? i would really be glad if anyone would help me (sry but this text is just for making it able to post this question because for some reason my question do not live up to their standards so just ignore this text :) ) :)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:
(where `mc` is the symbol and `scoreTXT` is the textbox)

```
Object(mc).scoreTXT.text = "Whatever text you want to display";
```

I hope this works for you. Let me know about the results you get.

Hope I helped! :D

Comment: Thanks for your time but it dosent work i get this error code: 1120: Access of undefined property symbol1.

Comment: And my code is: Object(symbol1).test123.text = "Whatever text you want to display";

Comment: where are you putting this code? In the symbol or in the parent of the symbol?

Comment: Its not placed in the symbol :)

Comment: are you sure the symbol has an instance name? you can apply one by clicking on the symbol, going to the properties panel, and typing `symbol1` on the <Instance Name> textbox.

Comment: hehe thanks for your help :) your code was just right im just the dump one here ^^ i doubled checked your code too and saw i made something wrong ^^ thanks :)

Comment: Just and other question do you know how to do this if its a button? or a way to import your variables inside a button so you can use this fuction inside the button??

Comment: One way is to make a class for the button, then put the variables inside the class.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) but would be nice and give me an example of the  code i should use :)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible, and should be relatively easy. Did you check that the text field is a dynamic text field and that you have named the instance of that textfield in the symbol?

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: Yes every thing is as i said and i have even just double checked it :)

Comment: I believe this was the actual issue. The code in the the accepted answer isn't needed if the instance name is actually set properly and wasn't misspelled in code. Casting the instance as an Object in no way solved this issue. So +1 to to the sturgeon, even though he won't get credit.

Comment: @putvande - dont agree. The question asks is this possible. I give the definitive answer (yes) and suggest a possible problem that could be causing the issue. That seems cromulent. The question itself is a simple question, asking for a simple clear answer.  And now this comment is longer than my answer *sigh*